# Make command line unmodifiable in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I am running Aquamacs on OSX.

Let's say I open a shell:

```
M-x-shell
```

I find it annoying that I can press backspace and it will delete the command line prompt

```
>
```

and also that I can delete sections of previously entered commands in the command line.

Is there a way to make the command line un-editable?

Comment: In a prior answer that has been removed, I indicated that setting the variable `comint-prompt-read-only` to `t` would likely achieve the desired effect.  You replied by stating that you did not have a full version of Emacs installed and needed to download `comint.el`.  I am not able to assist you in getting a partial installation of Emacs to work correctly.  If after installing a full version of Emacs you are unable to achieve the desired affect with `(setq comint-prompt-read-only t`), then please revise your question and provide additional details.

Comment: As stated, I am using Aquamacs and it is fully installed. I placed the line in the Preferences.el file and it seems to solve the problem partially. I am now unable to delete the latest line but I can still click somewhere above and delete those entries. Is there an extra command to disable that? thanks for your help

Comment: I use the following settings to set the process output as read-only -- it is too long to fit into one comment, so I'm spreading it out over two comments [**part one of two**]:  `(setq comint-use-prompt-regexp t) (defvar my-local-shells  '("*tex-shell*" "*shell0*" "*shell1*" "*shell2*" "*shell3*" "*music*")) (defvar my-remote-shells '("*snarfed*" "*heaven0*" "*heaven1*" "*heaven2*" "*heaven3*")) (defvar my-shells (append my-local-shells my-remote-shells))`

Comment: This is the second part -- you *may* experience a slow-down with **voluminous** outputs [**part two of two**]:  `(defun make-my-shell-output-read-only (text) (when (member (buffer-name) my-shells) (let* ( (inhibit-read-only t) (beg comint-last-output-start) (end (process-mark (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))) ) (or (= (point-min) beg) (get-text-property (1- beg) 'read-only) (put-text-property (1- beg) beg 'read-only 'fence)) (add-text-properties beg end '(read-only t front-sticky (read-only)))))) (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'make-my-shell-output-read-only)`